# Kubernetes service account doesn't have token?

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I have a few kubernetes service accounts.

I want to login kubernetes dashboard.

```
$kubectl get sa -n kubernetes-dashboard
NAME                   SECRETS   AGE
whitebear              0         9m37s
default                0         15m
kubernetes-dashboard   0         15m
```

However service account does'nt have token.

```
$kubectl describe sa whitebear -n kubernetes-dashboard
Name:                whitebear
Namespace:           kubernetes-dashboard
Labels:              <none>
Annotations:         <none>
Image pull secrets:  <none>
Mountable secrets:   <none>
Tokens:              <none>
Events:              <none>
```

How can I create the token for account?

I am using docker for mac, local environement.

Thank you  very much.

**Solution**

thanks to @Sai Chandini Routhu!!

I made token and login successfuly

```
kubectl create token default
```

However it was not enough to use dashboard

I make cluster role

```
kind: ClusterRole
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  namespace: default
  name: service-reader
rules:
- apiGroups: [""] # "" indicates the core API group
  resources: ["*"]
  verbs: ["*"]
```

then bind this to my account.

```
kubectl create clusterrolebinding service-reader-pod \
  --clusterrole=service-reader  \
  --serviceaccount=default:whitebear
```

Now I can login and operate dashboard!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any processes or applications running inside the pod of the Kubernetes cluster can gain access to the cluster by obtaining service account authentication from the API server.

AS per this [doc](https://medium.com/the-programmer/working-with-service-account-in-kubernetes-df129cb4d1cc) by @pramodAIML

> When you create a pod, if you do not specify a service account, it is
> automatically assigned the default service account in the same
> namespace.
>
> **For describing the service account:**
>
> you have to type the following kubectl command:
>
> ```
> Kubectl describe service account my- web page-sa
> ```
>
> So if you carefully watch the output you will see that the Tokens
> attribute is created with the value.This token is stored as a secret
> object, this secret object is attached to the service
> account:my-webpage-sa.
>
> **To view the secret object :**
>
> If you want to view whats the content of the secrte object we can type
> the following command
>
> ```
> $ kubectl describe secret <token-value>
> ```
>
> To obtain the necessary data from the Kubernetes cluster API server,
> this key can be exchanged as an authentication bearer token in your
> REST API call.

Refer this [doc](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/cloud-paks/cp-management/2.0.0?topic=kubectl-using-service-account-tokens-connect-api-server) for more information about Using service account tokens to connect with the API server

Answer (score 4):

Tokens are not generated by default for ServiceAccounts since Kubernetes version 1.22. To create a long-lived ServiceAccount token in a Secret, see [this documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-service-account/#manually-create-an-api-token-for-a-serviceaccount), which says:

> If you want to obtain an API token for a ServiceAccount, you create a new Secret with a special annotation, `kubernetes.io/service-account.name`.
>
> ```
> kubectl apply -f - <<EOF
> apiVersion: v1
> kind: Secret
> metadata:
>   name: build-robot-secret
>     annotations:
>         kubernetes.io/service-account.name: build-robot
>         type: kubernetes.io/service-account-token
> EOF
> ```
>
> If you view the Secret using:
>
> ```
> kubectl get secret/build-robot-secret -o yaml
> ```
>
> you can see that the Secret now contains an API token for the "build-robot" ServiceAccount.